# ¿Hay un problema en el preview de las tablas escritas en Markdown?

Tags: bug

Estoy redactando [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/604699/29967) y la tabla que está al final se ve bien en el preview (antes de publicar la respuesta):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando publico la respuesta, se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Por qué me engaña el preview y cómo puedo resolver esto?

Comment: Lo vi y pense que era un error de tu parte.. dejame chequearlo de vuelta...

Comment: Listo, te lo arregle... le molestaba el fiddle demasiado pegado :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sip, es un bug, y su correspondiente reporte esta [aca](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360020/141717).

Para evitar eso, hay que poner un espacio después de la ultima fila de la tabla.

Desgraciadamente, pasaron 2 años y no lo solucionaron, pero ahí esta explicado porque pasa...

Comment: De acuerdo. Gracias.